# Calculate the area of a polygon drawn on google maps in an Android application

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, polygon

I would like to calculate the are of a polygon drawn in a map fragment for a college project.

This is how I draw my polygon.

```
@Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
        //tvLocInfo.setText("New marker added@" + point.toString());
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point).draggable(true).title(point.toString()));

        markerClicked = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
        //tvLocInfo.setText("New marker added@" + point.toString());
        map.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

        if(markerClicked){

            if(polygon != null){
                polygon.remove();
                polygon = null;
            }

            polygonOptions.add(marker.getPosition());
            polygonOptions.strokeColor(Color.RED);
            polygonOptions.fillColor(Color.BLUE);
            polygon = map.addPolygon(polygonOptions);
            //Area = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea(polygon.getPath().getArray());
        }else{
            if(polygon != null){
                polygon.remove();
                polygon = null;
            }

            polygonOptions = new PolygonOptions().add(marker.getPosition());
            markerClicked = true;
        }
```

I have seen this code on how to calculate the area but I am unsure how to implement it in my application and calculate the area of my polygon.

I use this code to calculate an area of a GPS with Android:

```
  private static final double EARTH_RADIUS = 6371000;// meters

  public static double calculateAreaOfGPSPolygonOnEarthInSquareMeters(final List<Location> locations) {
    return calculateAreaOfGPSPolygonOnSphereInSquareMeters(locations, EARTH_RADIUS);
  }

  private static double calculateAreaOfGPSPolygonOnSphereInSquareMeters(final List<Location> locations, final double radius) {
    if (locations.size() < 3) {
      return 0;
    }

    final double diameter = radius * 2;
    final double circumference = diameter * Math.PI;
    final List<Double> listY = new ArrayList<Double>();
    final List<Double> listX = new ArrayList<Double>();
    final List<Double> listArea = new ArrayList<Double>();
    // calculate segment x and y in degrees for each point
    final double latitudeRef = locations.get(0).getLatitude();
    final double longitudeRef = locations.get(0).getLongitude();
    for (int i = 1; i < locations.size(); i++) {
      final double latitude = locations.get(i).getLatitude();
      final double longitude = locations.get(i).getLongitude();
      listY.add(calculateYSegment(latitudeRef, latitude, circumference));
      Log.d(LOG_TAG, String.format("Y %s: %s", listY.size() - 1, listY.get(listY.size() - 1)));
      listX.add(calculateXSegment(longitudeRef, longitude, latitude, circumference));
      Log.d(LOG_TAG, String.format("X %s: %s", listX.size() - 1, listX.get(listX.size() - 1)));
    }

    // calculate areas for each triangle segment
    for (int i = 1; i < listX.size(); i++) {
      final double x1 = listX.get(i - 1);
      final double y1 = listY.get(i - 1);
      final double x2 = listX.get(i);
      final double y2 = listY.get(i);
      listArea.add(calculateAreaInSquareMeters(x1, x2, y1, y2));
      Log.d(LOG_TAG, String.format("area %s: %s", listArea.size() - 1, listArea.get(listArea.size() - 1)));
    }

    // sum areas of all triangle segments
    double areasSum = 0;
    for (final Double area : listArea) {
      areasSum = areasSum + area;
    }

    // get abolute value of area, it can't be negative
    return Math.abs(areasSum);// Math.sqrt(areasSum * areasSum);
  }

  private static Double calculateAreaInSquareMeters(final double x1, final double x2, final double y1, final double y2) {
    return (y1 * x2 - x1 * y2) / 2;
  }

  private static double calculateYSegment(final double latitudeRef, final double latitude, final double circumference) {
    return (latitude - latitudeRef) * circumference / 360.0;
  }

  private static double calculateXSegment(final double longitudeRef, final double longitude, final double latitude,
      final double circumference) {
    return (longitude - longitudeRef) * circumference * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(latitude)) / 360.0;
  }
```

I could also use the following polygon which is static if calculating the area of the drawn polygon is not possible.

```
Polygon UCCpolygon = map.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions()
    .add(new LatLng(51.893728, -8.491865), 
         new LatLng(51.893550, -8.492479), 
         new LatLng(51.893216, -8.492224), 
         new LatLng(51.893404, -8.491598))
 .strokeColor(Color.RED)
 .fillColor(Color.BLUE));
```

Thanks for the help!

Sean

Comment: First you need to get the `LatLng` from the `polygon`, use the `getHoles()`, the class is [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polygon.html). And use algorithm [here](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080213175333AASYvUd), also you can refer to [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9601816/calculate-earth-convex-hull-polygon-area-given-latitude-and-longitude).

Comment: Hi,Thanks so much for the reply!

public List<List<LatLng>> getHoles(){
  return polygon.getHoles();
 }

Is this correct?

Sorry but I do not know how to go about applying the algorithms you suggested!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's already a [library](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/SphericalUtil.html#computeArea(java.util.List)) for that.

```
import com.google.maps.android.SphericalUtil;

//...

List<LatLng> latLngs = new ArrayList<>();
latLngs.add(new LatLng(51.893728, -8.491865));
latLngs.add(new LatLng(51.893550, -8.492479));
latLngs.add(new LatLng(51.893216, -8.492224));
latLngs.add(new LatLng(51.893404, -8.491598));
Log.i(TAG, "computeArea " + SphericalUtil.computeArea(latLngs));
```

For me the output is `computeArea 1920.8879882782069`

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

How can I apply it to the polygon I create with polygonOptions as seen here?

I've been trying all day with no luck!

Comment: the method takes a List of LatLng as parameter so apart of creating Polygon, create also a List out of the same LatLngs

Comment: I have added the list of LatLng from my polygon and use the following code as you said but I am getting a value of 0 returned.
 `public double computeArea(java.util.List<LatLng> points){
  
return area;

 }`

Comment: Then you're doing sth wrong - probably no LatLng was added to the list. Check my edited answer.

Comment: The LatLng points are definitely in the list. This is the list `ArrayList<LatLng> points;`

This is how I add the point then `public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
  //tvLocInfo.setText("New marker added@" + point.toString());
  map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point).draggable(true).title(point.toString()));
  points.add(point);
  Toast.makeText(this,""+ point, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  markerClicked = false;
 }`

Is this correct?

Comment: What is the measuring units return for the library? How can I get Hectar?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use SphericalUtils code without any library, you can use following code. it's taken from opensource code from SphericalUtils.java and other class. I have taken this code and used it as i was using MapBox and MapBox does not have implemented the calculateArea function in Turf.

```
import java.util.List;

import pojo.LatLng;

import static java.lang.Math.PI;
import static java.lang.Math.abs;
import static java.lang.Math.atan2;
import static java.lang.Math.cos;
import static java.lang.Math.sin;
import static java.lang.Math.tan;
import static java.lang.Math.toRadians;

public class PolygonUtils {

    /**
     * The earth's radius, in meters.
     * Mean radius as defined by IUGG.
     */
    static final double EARTH_RADIUS = 6371009;

    /**
     * Returns the area of a closed path on Earth.
     * @param path A closed path.
     * @return The path's area in square meters.
     */
    public static double computeArea(List<LatLng> path) {
        return abs(computeSignedArea(path,EARTH_RADIUS));
    }

    /**
     * Returns the signed area of a closed path on a sphere of given radius.
     * The computed area uses the same units as the radius squared.
     * Used by SphericalUtilTest.
     */
    static double computeSignedArea(List<LatLng> path, double radius) {
        int size = path.size();
        if (size < 3) { return 0; }
        double total = 0;
        LatLng prev = path.get(size - 1);
        double prevTanLat = tan((PI / 2 - toRadians(prev.getLatitude())) / 2);
        double prevLng = toRadians(prev.getLongitude());
        // For each edge, accumulate the signed area of the triangle formed by the North Pole
        // and that edge ("polar triangle").
        for (LatLng point : path) {
            double tanLat = tan((PI / 2 - toRadians(point.getLatitude())) / 2);
            double lng = toRadians(point.getLongitude());
            total += polarTriangleArea(tanLat, lng, prevTanLat, prevLng);
            prevTanLat = tanLat;
            prevLng = lng;
        }
        return total * (radius * radius);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the signed area of a triangle which has North Pole as a vertex.
     * Formula derived from "Area of a spherical triangle given two edges and the included angle"
     * as per "Spherical Trigonometry" by Todhunter, page 71, section 103, point 2.
     * See http://books.google.com/books?id=3uBHAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA71
     * The arguments named "tan" are tan((pi/2 - latitude)/2).
     */
    private static double polarTriangleArea(double tan1, double lng1, double tan2, double lng2) {
        double deltaLng = lng1 - lng2;
        double t = tan1 * tan2;
        return 2 * atan2(t * sin(deltaLng), 1 + t * cos(deltaLng));
    }
}
```