# How to implement the geoplotting?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am able to get the geo plots of the land mass from the user and the requirement is to calculate the area of the land according to the plotted points.

I am unable to access the Google Maps in some Android phone and not able to calculate the area when I get geo plots in some phones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For calculating area you can check this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28838287/calculate-the-area-of-a-polygon-drawn-on-google-maps-in-an-android-application?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

You can also use [This lib](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=spatialite-android-tutorial) this is very useful for android GIS solution.

For some mobile which not showing google map it may be

1. Due to very poor internet connection
2. May be those devices have google services disabled.